# I want to show only categories in the legend of a highchart treemap. Is there a way to do that using shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, highcharts, treemap

I want to make a treemap to get an impression of the sizes in one `data.frame`. Let me show you an example:

[image: World population plot without legend]

I use the following code to produce this chart:

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)


ui <- fluidPage(
  highchartOutput("hcontainer")
)
 

server <- function(input, output){
  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({  
    gapminder %>%
      filter(year  == 2007) %>% 
      data_to_hierarchical(group_vars = c(continent, country), 
                                        size_var = pop,
                                        colors = c('pink','yellow','blue','green','orange','red')) %>% 
      hchart(type = "treemap"
             #showInLegend = TRUE,
             #legendType='point',
             )  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,
         server,
         options = list(launch.browser = TRUE)
         )
```

I saw it is possible to create a legend by uncommenting those two lines of code in the `hchart`-function, but the result is not what I want:

[image: World population plot with legend]

Is there a way to tell highcharts that I only want the continents in my legend?
As a less important sidenote: There seems to be a bug in the highcharts, because after clicking on the legend (which you can use to hide/make reappear countries), they change their color in the legend according to their continent:

[image: World population plot with legend after interacting with legend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following plugin to achieve that:

```
(function(H) {
  let pick = H.pick,
    defined = H.defined,
    fireEvent = H.fireEvent
  H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype.getAllItems = function(p) {
    var allItemsFirst = [],
      allItems = [];
    this.chart.series.forEach(function(series) {
      var seriesOptions = series && series.options;
      // Handle showInLegend. If the series is linked to another series,
      // defaults to false.
      if (series && pick(seriesOptions.showInLegend, !defined(seriesOptions.linkedTo) ? void 0 : false, true)) {
        // Use points or series for the legend item depending on
        // legendType
        allItemsFirst = allItems.concat(series.legendItems ||
          (seriesOptions.legendType === 'point' ?
            series.data :
            series));
      }
    });

    allItemsFirst.forEach(el => {
      if (el.isVisibleInLegend) {
        allItems.push(el)
      }
    })

    fireEvent(this, 'afterGetAllItems', {
      allItems: allItems
    });
    return allItems;
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

And set `isVisibleInLegend: true` for each point from you expect to be in the legend.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: "treemap",
    layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
    showInLegend: true,
    legendType: 'point',
    data: [{
      id: "id_1",
      name: 'A',
      isVisibleInLegend: true
    }, {
      id: "id_2",
      name: 'A1',
      value: 2,
      parent: 'id_1',
    }, {
      id: "id_3",
      name: 'A2',
      value: 2,
      parent: 'id_1',
    }]
  }]
});
```

**JS Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vdqtok9m/

**Extending Highcharts:**
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Can you explain how to add this javascript code to my R document? And maybe point out a good resource?

Comment: To make it work in R, you can wrap this function in `chart.load` event. Example thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53613622/highcharter-multiple-tooltips-open-with-hidedelay/53654066#53654066

Comment: I uncommented the `legendType` and `showInLegend` parts of my code and added a `chart = list(events = list(load = JS(" *your code* ")))` after that but unfortunately now I do not see any legend. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Apologize! Forgot to mention, that you need to set `isVisibleInLegend: true` for each point that you want to include in the legend.

Comment: I ended up modifying the R-function `data_to_hierarchical` and wrote my own function `data_to_hierarchical_enhanced` which is basically the same, but I added `if (depth == 1)  {dd <- dd %>% append(list('isVisibleInLegend'=TRUE))}` directly after the already existing command `if (depth != 1){dd <- dd %>% append(list(datg_parent))}`. Now if you uncomment `legendType` and `showInLegend` in the code of my question and use `data_to_hierarchical_enhanced` instead of `data_to_hierarchical` it works.
Thanks for your support!